# UI XCTest recording with unicode characters in XCode 7 gives wrong Swift code

Tags: xcode, swift, xctest, ui-testing

Right now when recording an element on my app, it returns something along the lines of:

```
XCUIApplication().alerts["\U201cMy Application\U201d Would Like to Send You Notifications"].staticTexts["Notifications may include alerts, sounds, and icon badges. These can be configured in Settings."].tap()
```

Which throws a compiler error. I then changed it to this, to follow the swift convention on references unicode characters:

```
XCUIApplication().alerts["\u{201c}My Application\u{201d} Would Like to Send You Notifications"].staticTexts["Notifications may include alerts, sounds, and icon badges. These can be configured in Settings."].tap()
```

This does compile, but the test fails because Swift does not find the element when testing. I then tried this:

```
XCUIApplication().alerts["“My Application” Would Like to Send You Notifications"].staticTexts["Notifications may include alerts, sounds, and icon badges. These can be configured in Settings."].tap()
```

Which has the same result.

I realize that this is likely a bug with xcode, but is there a workaround? The issue seems to have been around for awhile.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your error. Using the swift convention `\u{201c}`works great. U can also try using just a backslash if you want to use quotation marks

```
"\"MyApp\" Would Like to Send You Notifications"
```

You message indicates that you want to react to a system notification rather than your own UIAlert. Thats why you can't find it. Try setting up an UI Interuption Alert before the Alert appears and then react to it:

```
    addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription("\"MyApp\" Would Like to Send You Notifications") {
        (alert) -> Bool in
        alert.buttons["OK"].tap()
        return true
    }
```

Also consider Joe Masilotti's excellent [Cheat Sheet](http://masilotti.com/ui-testing-cheat-sheet/#how-to-interact-with-a-system-alert) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround for Xcode 7.1 bug in UI XCTest recording unicode titles (Swift)**

1. Record all actions you want as usual.
2. Copy generated code
3. Open this [online unicode converter tool](http://www.mobilefish.com/services/unicode_escape_sequence_converter/unicode_escape_sequence_converter.php)
4. Paste your code in "Unicode characters*" text area
5. Select conversion direction: Unicode characters to unicode escape sequences
6. Click Convert button
7. Copy converted code from "Unicode escape sequences" text area in your program

That all. I hope Apple will fix this bug soon.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and I fixed it with this code below:

```
let notificationAlertElement = XCUIApplication().alerts["\u{201c}My Application\u{201d} Would Like to Send You Notifications"].staticTexts["Notifications may include alerts, sounds, and icon badges. These can be configured in Settings."].collectionViews.buttons["OK"]

    if (notificationAlertElement.exists) {
        notificationAlertElement.tap()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't get "addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription" working. So, the solution I use is to not register for notification if in simulator.

```
//Because simulator does not have to have notifications, ust disable it.
#if !arch(i386) && !arch(x86_64)
    //Ask the user to accept notifications from the application    
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Alert, categories: nil))
#endif
```